# Apache File Query

Tags: apache-2.2, files, query

I have an Apache server that has multiple files located on it. Each file is an updated version from the previous file. Eg. release-2013-07-20 is an older file and release-2013-07-25 is the newer file.

I am looking to query the apache server and have an display of the most updated file via website link.

I am unsure how to go about accomplishing this and I am looking for some suggestions.

Thank you, Tyler

Comment: So, you're looking at distributing the "latest" version of a given file? You need a front-end app (a download script). Apache can't do this on its own.

Comment: How are the files getting uploaded to the Apache server?  Can you just add/update a symbolic link that points to the latest version of the file?

Comment: This question appears like it would be a better fit on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `mod_autoindex` and an apache version of 2.0.23 or greater, you can add `?C=M` to your url and it will sort by last modified date and then by file name (provided `IndexOptions IgnoreClient` has not been set). Provided your latest file is the last file uploaded/updated this should solve your issue.

If you have a number of files in a directory and just want to display the latest then I'd agree with Zoredache - you'd need to develop a script to present that, or symlink the latest file:

`ln -s release-2013-07-25 latest-release`

and provide 'latest-release' as the link to the latest file.